# How to pass credentials and download file from a URL on 11g Oracle (PL/SQL)?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g

I am trying to write a plsql procedure to download a file from a given url in another system. This system requires a userid and password to access.  when i try the below procedure(Basically this [script](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2145641)), i am getting an error:

> ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: hex to raw conversion error

It is coming from this line: `utl_http.set_header(l_http_request, 'Authorization', 'Basic ' || utl_encode.base64_encode('userid:passwd'));`
Which i added to pass credentials.

If I comment it, this error goes away but i get: `Authorization Required.This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the document requested."`

Procedure code is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE APPS.load_binary_from_url (p_url  IN  VARCHAR2) AS 
  l_http_request   UTL_HTTP.req;
  l_http_response  UTL_HTTP.resp;
  l_blob           BLOB;
  l_raw            RAW(32767);
  l_url            VARCHAR2(300); 

BEGIN
  -- Initialize the BLOB.
  DBMS_LOB.createtemporary(l_blob, FALSE);  
  l_url :=p_url; 

  -- Make a HTTP request and get the response.
  l_http_request  := UTL_HTTP.begin_request(l_url); 
  utl_http.set_header(l_http_request, 'Authorization', 'Basic ' || utl_encode.base64_encode('userid:passwd'));
  l_http_response := UTL_HTTP.get_response(l_http_request);

  -- Copy the response into the BLOB.
  BEGIN
    LOOP
        UTL_HTTP.read_raw(l_http_response, l_raw, 32767);
        DBMS_LOB.writeappend (l_blob, UTL_RAW.length(l_raw), l_raw);
    END LOOP;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN UTL_HTTP.end_of_body THEN
      UTL_HTTP.end_response(l_http_response);
  END;

  -- Insert the data into the table.
  INSERT INTO http_blob_test (id, url, data)
  VALUES (http_blob_test_seq.NEXTVAL, p_url, l_blob);
  COMMIT;

  -- Relase the resources associated with the temporary LOB.
  DBMS_LOB.freetemporary(l_blob);
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    UTL_HTTP.end_response(l_http_response);
    DBMS_LOB.freetemporary(l_blob);
    RAISE;
END load_binary_from_url;
/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`utl_encode.base64_encode` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/u_encode.htm#ARPLS70869) takes a RAW argument, not a VARCHAR2, so you have to convert the value first. You can see the same thing (with a slightly different message) in plain SQL:

```
select utl_encode.base64_encode('userid:passwd') from dual;

SQL Error: ORA-01465: invalid hex number
```

You can use the [`utl_i18n.string_to_raw` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/u_i18n.htm#ARPLS71164) to convert the string to RAW:

```
select utl_encode.base64_encode(utl_i18n.string_to_raw('userid:passwd', 'AL32UTF8'))
from dual;

UTL_ENCODE.BASE64_ENCODE(UTL_I18N.STRING_TO_RAW('USERID:PASSWD','AL32UTF8'))   
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
64584E6C636D6C6B4F6E426863334E335A413D3D
```

Depending on your client and settings that may display as above or be implicitly shown converted back from raw; e.g. SQL Fiddle displays it as `ZFhObGNtbGtPbkJoYzNOM1pBPT0=`. But concatenating it leaves it in the raw form.

You need another step to explicitly convert to a usable string value:

```
select utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(utl_encode.base64_encode(utl_i18n.string_to_raw('userid:passwd', 'AL32UTF8'))) from dual;

UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(UTL_ENCODE.BASE64_ENCODE(UTL_I18N.STRING_TO_RAW('USERID
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
dXNlcmlkOnBhc3N3ZA==
```

and the same value is then preserved when concatenated with the `Basic` prefix.

You can do the same thing in your procedure:

```
  utl_http.set_header(l_http_request, 'Authorization',
    'Basic ' || utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(utl_encode.base64_encode(
      utl_i18n.string_to_raw('userid:passwd', 'AL32UTF8'))));
```

... optionally storing the RAW values in their own variables first for legibility.

Comment: Hi Alex, You were absolutely right. This has got rid off the error. But still I am not able to fetch the file. I am getting an htm file with "Authorization Required.This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the document requested." (I have validated the user id i am using via browser)

Comment: @manumuraleedharan - yes, missed that you need to convert the RAW result back to a string. Updated the answer to show that. You might want to examine the headers from a manual request (via your browser's developer tools) to compare the HTTP header you get there with the one this generates.

Comment: excellent @AlexPoole you saved my day one more time ! Regards

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue today and it was workarounded using:

```
  utl_http.set_header(l_http_request, 'Authorization',
    'Basic ' || utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(utl_encode.base64_encode(
      utl_i18n.string_to_raw('userid:passwd', 'UTF8'))));
```

Note: I'm using Oracle Database EE 11GR2